# Add sum of columns to chart SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have searched all over and cannot seem to find a definitive answer for this issue! I have a simple chat here grouped on the 5 categories below detailing the Sums of their SqFt.

[image]

I want to add a Total Column to the graph ~(Total = 11M sqft). Can this only be done in SQL? It is a bit puzzling for me to do this because the query already sums the sqft for each row (as a nested query). I would need to `Sum(sum(sqft))` in order to produce what I want, however, I dont believe this will work on the group level.

Sample Data set:

```
ID| Type| Sqft|

12| OF| 500

14| IN| 1294

99| OF| 12042

24| ME| 92043

15| IN| 13945

16| OW| 2650
```

Can this be done in the report builder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Total row in your query by using [GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx) operator. Once the total is in the dataset it is trivial to show the column in the chart.

Based on the data sample you posted you can use a similar query to the below:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN GROUPING_ID(Type) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL'
    ELSE Type
  END [Type],
  SUM(Sqft) Sqft,
  GROUPING_ID(Type) [Grouping]
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Type), ())
```

Check this <kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/450639/adding-total-row)</kbd>

If you are confused by the above query you can simply use the union operator to add a row to the end of your current dataset.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  [Type],
  Sqft
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT
  NULL,
  'Total',
  SUM(Sqft)
FROM your_table
```

Now just create your chart using the produced dataset.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this with `UNION ALL` in my SQL query. Thank you!